# .gif image as canvas background

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, background

I want to set a .gif image as a background image of a canvas so that i would get an animated view of the background.but i was getting only a static image displayed on it.

Here is my HTML code of my windows 8 app.

```
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <img id="scream" src="images/gangam.gif" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">
</body>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); // Create canvas context                                                                          

  function paintCanvas() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img, W/2, H/2);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not letting the canvas be transparent, and placing (CSS positioning) the canvas above it? Isn't this better than having to do low-level imaging stuff?

Otherwise canvas shows only one static image at a time, of course your JavaScript could animate it but that doesn't it's staticness.

Check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pK7Xx/2/

**CSS**

```
#canvas, #scream {
    width: 500px;
    height: 212px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

#canvas {
    margin-top: -212px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="scream" src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ma1wafniaA1rbonrno1_500.gif" alt="The Scream">
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**Draw Using a Transparent Canvas**
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
          context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // Create canvas context

```
function something() {
context.font = "bold 25px sans-serif";
context.fillText("Hello!", 100, 43);
}

something();
```

Comment: What does this part of the code do #canvas {
    margin-top: -212px;
}  also I am looking to make a game and need to find out which is the best way to animate more than one object on a canvas. Should I just draw all of the object on the same canvas or should I move them to different canvases. This is something that I have been wondering for some time. Or should I use more than one canvas and make all of them transparent and have each object on a canvas. Which is the best way of doing this?

Comment: How does the image keep animating it self to look like the guy is jumping and horse heads are moving.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to show a `.gif` in `<canvas>`. You might use [sprites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29) and `setInterval()` to imitate animation.